ActionText does not displaying images in Rails 7.x
For any reason, images are not showing after upgrade from Rails 6.0.x to 7.1.4.2.
I have this in the partial:
<%= comment.comment %>

Debugging comment.comment:
comment.comment.class

ActionText::RichText(id: integer, name: string, body: text, record_type: string, record_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

comment.comment.body

<ActionText::Content "<div><action-text-atta...">

comment.comment.body.to_html

"<div><action-text-attachment sgid=\"eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaEpJalpuYVdRNkx5OW9aV3h3WkdWemF5OUJZM1JwZG1WVGRHOXlZV2RsT2pwQ2JHOWlMelF4TlQ5bGVIQnBjbVZ6WDJsdUJqb0dSVlE9IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJhdHRhY2hhYmxlIn19--cc95219c843a2e5aef1d6178613a6bb6478ca9cb\" content-type=\"image/png\" url=\"http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBcDhCIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--41601a8549889e64d317ee1f4fd446a80419bad4/imagen.png\" filename=\"imagen.png\" filesize=\"30319\" width=\"834\" height=\"443\" presentation=\"gallery\"></action-text-attachment><br>prueba</div>"

But
raw comment.comment.body

"<div class=\"trix-content\">\n  <div>\n<action-text-attachment><figure>\n    <img>\n\n  <figcaption>\n    <a target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noreferer\">imagen.png</a><br>\n  </figcaption>\n</figure></action-text-attachment><br>prueba</div>\n</div>\n"

It can see that img tag does not have src attribute.  The retrieved HTML is uncompleted.

Check the following:

Install image_processing gem for image support in Rails 7.x.
Use rails_blob_url to add src to <img> in ActionText content.


In Gemfile: gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.13'.
In _blob.html.erb:  <%= image_tag rails_blob_url(blob) %>.
image_tag rails_blob_url(blob) returns:
"<img src="http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBcVVCIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--8864c9a2b39a1c14cc8d90ccfe5d5af4ba248d21/imagen.png" />".
src is a valid url.  It display the image if I put it in the internet navigator.

However, It is shown wrong in the page:
"<div class="trix-content">\n  \n\n    \n\n  \n    <a target="_blank" rel="noreferer">imagen.png\n  \nprueba\n\n"

Ensure that your _blob.html.erb partial is correctly named and located?

Of course Nilesh. I had to revert to Rails 7.0.7 to get it working properly.  I will recreate the bug in a controlled environment to try to fix it.

ok thanks for updates @Johan
